# Semantic logging vs wad logs table

Tags: c#, etw, azure-diagnostics, logging-application-block, semantic-logging

I want to decide between semantic logging for azure vs traditional logging where all logs use to go to wadlogs table. Is there any specific reason we should go for one or other? what is the difference between two and which one is preferable?

Answer (score 0):

Semantic logging is like strong typed logging messages. They give you consistency so an automated process (or a person) could filter through a log that could contain messages from multiple applications. It also centralizes the definition of what you can log. You can format a log message any way you want, but Azure and SQL sinks give the added benefit of persisting the entire payload. WAD logs are more geared for diagnostics and are not structured as they are stored as blobs.